# Webpack 4 remove / strip some parts of html

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am using **html-webpack-plugin** to process html files.
I need to remove some parts before i export for server. I found a couple plugins to do this but they are outdated or doesn't work with webpack 4.

This is my config for **html-webpack-plugin**.

[image]

I marked the parts i wanted to remove like this.

```
<!--deletestart--> 
  code to be removed.
<!--deleteend-->
```

[image]

Is there any working plugin or a way to do this with webpack 4? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe writing your own little plugin is an option? `html-webpack-plugin` provides a hook for that. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#events

Comment: I suggested an update for existing plugin. And the author quickly made the change. Thanks anyway. html-webpack-plugin-remove

Comment: Good. But I also just remembered, there is another way without a plugin. If you use `html-webpack-plugin`s templating and `<% if(foo) { %> html <% } %>`

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested an update for existing plugin. And the author quickly made the change. Thanks.

**html-webpack-plugin-remove**

https://github.com/alexblunck/html-webpack-plugin-remove

I can use it easily like this.

```
new HtmlPluginRemove(/<!--deletestart-->[\s\S]*<!--deleteend-->/gi),
```